# Doctrine 2 Console Tool says: You are missing a "cli-config.php" or "config/cli-config.php"

Tags: doctrine-orm, console, doctrine, configuration-files

I ran doctrine console tool:

```
$ php vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create --dump-sql
```

I got this instead of expected functionality:

```
You are missing a "cli-config.php" or "config/cli-config.php" file in your
project, which is required to get the Doctrine Console working. You can use the
following sample as a template:

<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner;

// replace with file to your own project bootstrap
require_once 'bootstrap.php';

// replace with mechanism to retrieve EntityManager in your app
$entityManager = GetEntityManager();

return ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($entityManager);
```

Issues:

- I am on ZF2, and there is no file called `bootstrap.php`
- I am new to ZF2, so I don't know what my entityManager is and what I should put for `GetEntityManager`

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## The Easy Way

**Use Doctrine Module:**

`vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create --dump-sql`

Note: this answer may be specific to these frameworks:

- Zend Framework
- Zend Expressive
- Laminas
- Mezzio

Comment: Some explanation would be great here!

Comment: Doctrine Console tool in my question expects an environment with a fully defined entity manager to be able to work.  `doctrine-module` tool must be using something else, or is a different tool altogether, as it does not require an entity manager to work.  Instead of figuring out how to define an entity manager, or how to define a ZF2 environment to be able to use doctrine console's schema-tool, I opted to use `doctrine-module` tool that did not require me to do any extra set up.

Comment: Gives me an error 'No such file or directory'
(I am using Symfony 2.7 btw ...)

Comment: 'No such file or directory' also for SF 3.4

Comment: Please elaborate on where this binary comes from, because some people use isolated Symfony packages instead of generating a project through the Symfony CLI. Is `doctrine-module` created upon installation of some composer package, or do you have reference to its project repository maybe?

Comment: I wrote this answer in context of Zend Framework (now Project Laminas).  I am not sure if this will work for Symfony.  You could try `composer require doctrine/doctrine-module` (see https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule), but chances are it may not work, since it's geared towards Zend/Laminas.  See my "Hard Way" answer - it is following Doctrine documentation, which is framework-agnostic.

Comment: If all else fails, read through the source doc (https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/configuration.html#obtaining-an-entitymanager), and pretend you are installing Doctrine from scratch separately from the framework. Doing that made things 100% clearer for me, when I was struggling with Doctrine setup back then.

Comment: Link in previous post was for version `2.6`.  Check out the newest at the time (`2.7`):  https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/configuration.html

Answer (score 5):

## The Hard Way

Put this into your `config/cli-config.php`:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner;
use DoctrineConnector\EntityManagerFactory;
include 'vendor/autoload.php'

global $container;
$container = require 'config/container.php';

$factory = new EntityManagerFactory();
$entityManager = $factory($container);
return ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($entityManager);
```

Put this into your `config/autoload/database.local.php`:

```
return [
   'doctrine' => [
        /*
         * Paths for Doctrine to find Entities
         */
        'paths' => array(
            "src/Blah/src/Entity",
        ),

        /*
         * Doctrine configuration parameters
         */
        'db_params' => array(
            'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
            'user' => 'user',
            'password' => 'password',
            'dbname' => 'dbname',
            'driverOptions' => array(
                1002 => 'SET NAMES UTF8MB4'
            )
        ),

        /*
         * Tells Doctrine what mode we want
         * For Production environment set to \Doctrine\Common\Proxy\AbstractProxyFactory::AUTOGENERATE_NEVER;
         */
        'is_dev_mode' => false
    ]
];
```

Create this class:  `EntityManagerFactory`

```
class EntityManagerFactory
{

    /**
     * Set Up & return Doctrine connection
     *
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     * @throws \RuntimeException
     * @return EntityManager
     */
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container): EntityManager
    {
        $config = $container->get('config');
        Assert::that($config)->keyExists('doctrine', "No Doctrine ORM Configuration Specified, check your 'config/autoload/database.local.php'");
        $paths = $config['doctrine']['paths'];
        $dbParams = $config['doctrine']['db_params'];
        $isDevMode = $config['doctrine']['is_dev_mode'];

        $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
        $config->setProxyDir("temp/proxies");
        $entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);

        /*
         * Enable native prepared statements
         */
        $pdo = $entityManager->getConnection()->getWrappedConnection();
        $pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

        /*
         * Allow Doctrine to persist boolean types
         */
        Type::overrideType('boolean', BooleanToIntType::class);
        return $entityManager;
    }
}
```

After that, things should work splendidly

Comment: What are you supposed to do when you don't have those files? Doctrine-docs don't give me any explanation on how to get those or where I should even look for them....

Comment: You can create them yourself.  i.e.  How did you set up Doctrine?  I used Composer `php composer.phar require "doctrine/orm"`.  If you don't have composer, install that first.  (There is little point in trying to wrestle Doctrine without it).  Then, create your own `bootstrap.php` file, copy it over to be just like the one in my first link, then edit it to add your specific database parameters.  Then, create your own `cli-config.php` just like in the 2nd link.

Comment: Yeah, seems like I don't have those files... No Idea why, maybe because I'm working in a custom version of a homestead environment. I installed everything with composer, but never dit the php composer.phar, just simple composer require ***. Anyway, I'll try to do it manually, thanks..

Comment: yes you have to write them yourself.  They are configuration files pertaining to your specific set up.  I suppose they are not included because different environments may have different configurations and they instruct you to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

### For those not using Zend Framework

I wanted to use the Doctrine console tools to validate mappings in a Symfony Bundle I was developing without having to create an entire Symfony Application just to test my work. I was able to make it work by following the Official Installation guide
[Here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/configuration.html)

**Notes**: Even though I just wanted to validate mappings, Doctrine still needed to connect to a real DB to run. Personally, using pdo_pgsql, I needed to use the `host` and `port` DBParams in addition to what the guide had.